# Как работает Java Spliterator

Tags: java

Есть `List list`. Я хочу пробежаться по всем элементам и удвоить их.

```
list.spliterator().forEachRemaining(e -> e*2);
```

В итоге мой лист остается неизменным.

Я могу это сделать так:

```
List newList = new ArrayList<>();
for(int e in list) {
    newList.add(e);
}
```

Но прошлый вариант короче. Я хочу это сделать с помощью лямбда-функции. Какие есть варианты?

Answer (score 5):

Здесь можно и без `spliterator`'а. Способы делятся на три типа.

1. изменяется исходный список

   - [`.replaceAll()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/List.html#replaceAll-java.util.function.UnaryOperator-) (спасибо [@zRrr](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/190934/zrrr)!)

     ```
     List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3);
     list.replaceAll(x -> x * 2);
     ```

     [(Ideone)](https://ideone.com/85NqDw)
   - Похоже на исходный вариант (цикл с индексами + методы [`.get()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/List.html#get-int-), [`.set()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/List.html#set-int-E-)):

     ```
     for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); ++i) {
         int x = list.get(i);
         list.set(i, x * 2);
     }
     ```

     [(Ideone)](https://ideone.com/veXLIC)
2. создаётся новый список с нужными элементами

   - [`.stream()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#stream--) + [`.map()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#map-java.util.function.Function-) + [`.collect()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#collect-java.util.stream.Collector-):

     ```
     List<Integer> listTransformed = list
         .stream()
         .map(x -> x * 2)
         .collect(Collectors.toList());
     ```

     [(Ideone)](https://ideone.com/RMe5Kj)
   - Исходный вариант:

     ```
     List<Integer> listTransformed = new ArrayList<>();
     for (int x : list) {
         newList.add(x * 2);
     }
     ```

     [(Ideone)](https://ideone.com/T8d8ig)
3. создаётся view object над исходным списком

   - Используя метод [`Lists.transform()`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Lists.html#transform-java.util.List-com.google.common.base.Function-) библиотеки [Guava](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#collect-java.util.stream.Collector-):

     ```
     Lists.transform(list, x -> x * 2);
     ```

Варианты, когда в результате получается массив вместо списка:

- [`.stream()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#stream--) + [`.mapToInt()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#mapToInt-java.util.function.ToIntFunction-) + [`.toArray()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#toArray--):

  ```
  int[] array = list
      .stream()
      .mapToInt(x -> x * 2)
      .toArray();
  ```

  [(Ideone)](https://ideone.com/67OrJL)

Comment: @zRrr, спасибо, всё остальное тогда получается не нужно)

Comment: не сказать, что не нужны, т.к. методы дают разный результат. `replaceAll` изменяет существующий список, стримы создают новый, `transform` создает вьюшку над исходным списком.